# Open XML in dnx5.0 / aspnext

Tags: asp.net, openxml, dnx, dnu

I'm trying to build an app that uses OpenXML in a dnx/aspnet next environment.

I've added added the OpenXML dependency to my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    ....
    "DocumentFormat.OpenXml": "2.5.0"
  }
```

However, when i try to run, i get this error:

```
The type 'Package' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0
```

It seems OpenXML depends on WindowsBase. I'm fearful that this won't work in linux/mac environment, as I can't find a nuget package or a dependency by this name.

Is there a way to add this WindowsBase .dll to a unix dnx project? Is there another way to utilize OpenXML or another word document library in unix via dnx?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that [mono has WindowsBase.dll](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/WindowsBase/WindowsBase.dll.sources).

Try adding a framework reference to it like in this example: https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/7ac7929aa575e17b3c271e4a7a0c164418de0395/misc/XreTestApps/FrameworkReferences/project.json#L2 but use `WindowBase` instead of `System.IO`

Comment: That worked - just a note, that this had to be placed in `frameworkAssemblies` not `dependencies`, just like the link above shows.